# how to refresh the variable output in multiple lines without screen clear

Tags: bash, refresh, file-monitoring

I'm trying to monitor a log file then display the count of specific request calls, the output will show the header line which has the names of each request "PUT GET HEAD" and below that the count of requests of each node per line.
I need to refresh the output of the variables that shows the count each 1 sec

the problem with the below code, the script keeps on deleting previous lines and go up to the top of the screen, while the output should be fixed and only the number of request should refresh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#variables
MYIP=$(ifconfig eth1|grep -w 'inet'| awk '{print $2}')
BASEIP=$(echo $XIP | cut -d"." -f-3)

MONPUT=$(cat $HTTPLOG  | grep -w "PUT" |awk '{print $9}'| grep -E "20"| wc -l)
MONHEAD=$(cat $HTTPLOG  | grep -w "HEAD" | awk '{print $9}'| grep -E "20" |wc -l)
MONGET=$(cat $HTTPLOG  | grep -w "GET" | awk '{print $9}'| grep -E "20" |wc -l)
MONDEL=$(cat $HTTPLOG  | grep -w "DELETE" | awk '{print $9}'| grep -E "20" |wc -l)


# header 
printf "%15s" "Node " |tr '\n' '\t'
printf "%15s"  'PUT'  | tr '\n' '\t'
printf "%15s" 'HEAD' | tr '\n' '\t'
printf "%15s"  'GET'  | tr '\n' '\t'
printf "%15s"  'DELETE'  | tr '\n' ' '

# starting the loop

while [[ true ]]
do 
i=(1)

for (( x=1; x<=3; x++))
do 
((i = i + 1))
NODEIP="$BASEIP.$i"
ssh $NODEIP printf "%15s" "$GETNAME" "$MONPUT" "$MONHEAD" "$MONGET" "$MONDEL"
done

echo -ne "\033[3A\r"
done
```

here is the expected output:

Node                 PUT   - HEAD  - GET   - DELETE 
 node-2            1849    2183    41387   0

#

node-3            5339    8534    40838   0

#

node-4            1829    2196    46503   0

#

expected output: should show the same as above while the numbers are refreshed every 1 sec

Comment: I thing [ncurse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) will do the job propertly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with UtLox that, generally speaking, `ncurses` is your best option.  With that in mind, please take a look at `bashsimplecurses`:

[Git repo](https://github.com/metal3d/bashsimplecurses)

[Tutorial](https://bashsimplecurses.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BasicTutorial/)

[Basic example](https://bashsimplecurses.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#another-example)